# JBOSS Application does not start, error Context initialization failed:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jboss

I am with the following error:

> Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private uaiContacts.repository.ContactRepository uaiContacts.service.ContactService.contactRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [uaiContacts.repository.ContactRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

This is the **class that is generating the error**:

```
package uaiContacts.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import uaiContacts.repository.ContactRepository;
import uaiContacts.model.Contact;
import uaiContacts.vo.ContactListVO;

@Service
@Transactional
public class ContactService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ContactListVO findAll(int page, int maxResults) {
        Page<Contact> result = executeQueryFindAll(page, maxResults);

        if(shouldExecuteSameQueryInLastPage(page, result)){
            int lastPage = result.getTotalPages() - 1;
            result = executeQueryFindAll(lastPage, maxResults);
        }

        return buildResult(result);
    }

    public void save(Contact contact) {
        contactRepository.save(contact);
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
    public void delete(int contactId) {
        contactRepository.delete(contactId);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ContactListVO findByNameLike(int page, int maxResults, String name) {
        Page<Contact> result = executeQueryFindByName(page, maxResults, name);

        if(shouldExecuteSameQueryInLastPage(page, result)){
            int lastPage = result.getTotalPages() - 1;
            result = executeQueryFindByName(lastPage, maxResults, name);
        }

        return buildResult(result);
    }

    private boolean shouldExecuteSameQueryInLastPage(int page, Page<Contact> result) {
        return isUserAfterOrOnLastPage(page, result) && hasDataInDataBase(result);
    }

    private Page<Contact> executeQueryFindAll(int page, int maxResults) {
        final PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, maxResults, sortByNameASC());

        return contactRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
    }

    private Sort sortByNameASC() {
        return new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name");
    }

    private ContactListVO buildResult(Page<Contact> result) {
        return new ContactListVO(result.getTotalPages(), result.getTotalElements(), result.getContent());
    }

    private Page<Contact> executeQueryFindByName(int page, int maxResults, String name) {
        final PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, maxResults, sortByNameASC());

        return contactRepository.findByNameLike(pageRequest, "%" + name + "%");
    }

    private boolean isUserAfterOrOnLastPage(int page, Page<Contact> result) {
        return page >= result.getTotalPages() - 1;
    }

    private boolean hasDataInDataBase(Page<Contact> result) {
        return result.getTotalElements() > 0;
    }
}
```

This is the **repository**:

```
package uaiContacts.repository;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import uaiContacts.model.Contact;

@Repository
public interface ContactRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Contact, Integer> {
    Page<Contact> findByNameLike(Pageable pageable, String name);
}
```

Comment: What should this be doing instead of generating an error?  What is your goal here, and how did you try to fix it?

Comment: Do you have the implementation class for ContactRepository in the context path?

Comment: Can you attached the repository configuration in your xml?

Comment: How would I do this in XML? for I am newbie...